# Get AdMob test device ids for both iOS and Android in Flutter project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I am trying to use my own/REAL AdUnits instead of the TestAdUnits but I have no idea where to get the Test Device Ids for my iOS and Android devices.

Docs say to look at the logs to locate the test id, but I have inspected everything that gets printed to the console and it does not print either of the devices test ids.

I am building and running my project in VS Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a while of looking through logs, I realized there are some missing steps in Flutter's package explanation.

First, Firebase needs to be linked to you AdMob app, AND you need to re-download the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file for iOS and the `google-services.json` for Android.

After that, in iOS you need to go into `Settings -> Privacy -> Advertising` and disable `Limit Ad Tracking`. This will allow for the ID to be printed.

Comment: Hi, its helpful for me, but I have still one doubt.
I didn't link admob to firebase but I can see admob works.
Can you please tell me why we need to link to firebase?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably searched on admob and adsense console.
maybe the google play developer console will be helpful.
For now im only using testAds since my app is not done yet.